# Dropdown inside Gridview is not retaining the background color when postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have an `<asp:DropDownList>` inside an `<asp:TemplateField>`in a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DatosTablaHandoff">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownGV" runat="server" onchange="SetDropDownListColor(this);">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select...</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Complete</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Running</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Waiting in SEV 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No Batch</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And I have a script in js to set an "item background color" depending on the Selected Item:

```
function SetDropDownListColor(ddl) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
            if (ddl.options[i].selected) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'White';
                        return;
                    case 1:
                        ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
                        return;
                    case 2:
                        ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
                        return;
                    case 3:
                        ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'orangered';
                        return;
                    case 4:
                        ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'Grey';
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is working all right. But When Postback, the color goes away. The DropDown in every row stays with the Selected Value as I want, but with background-color White.

I have this other script (outside the function), to "save" the color when postback, but it only works if the DropDownList is outside the GridView:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { SetDropDownListColor(document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>')); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give all your `DropDownList`'s a `CssClass` and then loop through that collection of elements to call your `SetDropDownListColor` function.

Something like this:

.NET

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownGV" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" onchange="SetDropDownListColor(this);">
```

JS

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var ddls = document.querySelectorAll(".ddl");
        for (var i = 0, length = ddls.length; i < length; i++) {
            SetDropDownListColor(ddls[i]);
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: The issue is that you are trying binding the load event to the template's drop down, which doesn't exist. As zgood says, you have to provide some way of identifying each of the different dropdowns. A class is the typical and easiest way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! it's not 100% correct because I had to made some changes, but it helps a lot! This is what works for me:

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var dropdowns = new Array();
            var gridview = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');
            dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('select');
            for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                SetDropDownListColor(dropdowns[i]);
            }
        }, false);

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! it's not 100% correct because I had to made some changes, but it helps a lot! This is what works for me:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var dropdowns = new Array(); 
var gridview = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>'); 
dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('select'); 
for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) { 
SetDropDownListColor(dropdowns[i]); } }, false);
```